# Can A Static Resource Be Accessed From Site?

Tags: force.com-sites, static-resources

Pretty simple question. I have a `VisualForce Page` on which I have the following line:

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.MyStyleSheet)}" />
```

When I access this page via a `Site`It's not loading, and when I look in the console I see this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Do I just have to inline everything?

Comment: I am sure you would have done your fair share of googling around, just in case you missed As per docs static resources are always private for force.com sites 1) Does the profile of the guest user IP/Login restricted ( I have hardly seen this feature being used, so guessing not)2) Has your site become a restricted site from non restricted, if so as per the docs it may take upto 45 days for the static resource to be available https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_resources_create.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dumb mistake, I created them through the `Developer Console`, where their `Cache Control` property defaulted to `private`. Changing it to `public` resolved the issue.

[image]